# Did turbofan engine explosions become more frequent in last years in commercial aviation?

Tags: turbofan, accident-statistics

There are many incidents with turbofan engine failures during last years. I can list:

- 2010-11-04 - [Qantas_Flight_32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qantas_Flight_32)
- 2015-09-08 - [British Airways Flight 2276](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Airways_Flight_2276)
- 2016-05-27 - [Korean Air Flight 2708](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Air_Flight_2708)
- 2016-06-27 - [Singapore Airlines Flight 368](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Airlines_Flight_368)
- 2016-10-28 - [American Airlines Flight 383](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_383_(2016))
- 2017-09-30 - [Air France 66](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_France_Flight_66)
- 2018-04-17 - [Southwest Airlines Flight 1380](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southwest_Airlines_Flight_1380)

This list is not exhaustive.

Question: **did turbofan incidents indeed become more frequent in recent years?**

If yes, is there a reason of this suggested?

Comment: Welcome to aviation.stackexchange!

Comment: Welcome. 1 or 3 per year in ~35 million flights (jet / commercial) per year does **not** reveal an increase in frequency, hence the question as posed cannot be answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

May depend on the time period of interest and what you count as an incident, but in general over the time span of decades, turbo fan engines are significantly more reliable now than they were previously. You only have to count the engines to see this trend. Many years ago all jets had 4 engines, then 3, and now virtually all new planes have only 2. The reason of this is the increasing reliability of engines. Decades ago planes had 4 engines because the possibility of 2 engines failing during a single flight, while uncommon, was not unheard of. Now days, planes have only 2 engines because reliability of engines is very good. Failure of 2 engines during the same flight is very very rare (maybe not zero, but very rare)